# Going to insert mode at the end of command with lua function

Tags: neovim, vimscript, insert-mode

I am using Neovim and I want to go to insert mode at the end of this command.

```lua
vim.cmd([[command! DunB lua run_only_current_file("below") ]])
```

I have tried `| startinsert` and `| :startinsert`.
but it did not work. The error says `unexpected symbol near |`.
I also put an `i` at the end of the command but it typed the whole command in the editor.
This is my function if it help:

```lua
function run_only_current_file(direction)
  local name=vim.fn.expand('%:t')
  local compiler="python" --defult
  local format=vim.fn.expand('%:e'):match('[^.]+$')
  if  format== 'py' then
    compiler="python"
  end
  if  format== 'js' then
    compiler="node"
  end
    vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(":" ..direction.. " split term://cd %:p:h &&" ..compiler.. " %:t\n","n", false)
end
```

Comment: try to use `:norm! A`

Comment: You may need to `:execute 'lua run_only_current_file("below")' | startinsert`; `:lua` is not documented as consuming the bar, but it probably does (`:python` and `:perl` do)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble No, `:norm! A`  gets error : `function arguments expected near '!' `. 
and `execute ....` will type  the content of the command in the editor.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thanks, your answer is perfect.

Comment: Thanks forbthe feedback :-) I'm happy I could help you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using `feedkeys`.

I suspect that `feedkey` will somehow trigger the next action asynchronously.

- Your function will first complete
- Neovim will treat the keys that you send via `feedkey`

The problem you have is that the buffer you want to enter in insert mode do not exist yet at that moment.

If you could you should get rid of the `feedkey` and replace it by an `execute` command:

```
direction .. " split term://cd %:p:h &&" ..compiler.. " %:t"
```

If that doesn't work because Neovim refuse to change the layout within that command then you can complete your mapping with `A`

```lua
 vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(":" ..direction.. " split term://cd %:p:h &&" ..compiler.. " %:t\nA","n", false)
```

Otherwise you could trigger a timer to enter in Insert mode after the feedkeys have been consumed by Neovim.

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe it depends on my function.